# try_files finds file but still goes to next one

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

this nginx config is supposed to load index.php from a folder (test), and if it doesn't exist then load index.php from parent folder.

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ ^/test/(.*)$ {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /test/index.php?$query_string /index.php?$query_string;

}
```

if I go to `/test` it works as expected.

but if I go to `/test/something` it loads `index.php` from root instead of the index.php from the parent folder.

Weirdly, if I remove the last `/index.php?$query_string` from the 2nd location block, then it actually loads the index.php from the parent folder.

So apparently the parent index is found, but for some reason nginx is deciding to look further.. Anyone know why?

Comment: Not a programming question

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the [`try_files`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) directive documentation carefully? The very last parameter, if not being specified as HTTP return code or a named location name, treated as a new URI to re-evaluate from the beginning. Every other parameter treated as a file name relative to the location root. That **does** include every character (well, except the last slash if being specified), so nginx will check the whole `$document_root/test/index.php?$query_string` file existence. The `?$query_string` part is not treated as an URI query string part here, but as a filename part. And even if such a file will be found, it will be served using this location content handler, which is a static one by default (unless you specified something else explicitly using the content handler declaration directive like `proxy_pass`, `fastcgi_pass`, `uwsgi_pass`, etc.)

The reason your PHP files gets processed with the PHP handler (usually something like `location ~ \.php$ { ... }`) even if your request URI doesn't include the PHP filename is either implicit redirect issued by the [`index`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html) directive if your `try_files` include the `$uri/` argument (read that one documentation carefully too) or explicit redirect issued via the last `/index.php?$query_string` parameter of the `try_files` directive. Here is a quote of the most relevant `index` documentation part to explain this with an example:

> It should be noted that using an index file causes an internal redirect, and the request can be processed in a different location. For example, with the following configuration:
>
> ```
> location = / {
>     index index.html;
> }
> location / {
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> a `/` request will actually be processed in the second location as `/index.html`.

Take into attention that the regex matching locations, while having a greater priority over the prefix ones (yes, the [`location`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) directive documentation is useful too), are checked in order of appearance, and the very first matched the URI will be chosen to handle the request.

**Summary**

Assuming your `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` PHP handler located **above** the `location ~ ^/test/(.*)$ { ... }`:

- If your URI is `/test/`, it is an implicit internal redirect to `/test/index.php` made by `index` directive that makes that file to be interpreted via the PHP handler;
- If your URI is `/test/something` and your `try_files` directive is `try_files $uri $uri/ /test/index.php?$query_string /index.php?$query_string;`, explicit internal redirect to `/index.php?$query_string` happens;
- If your URI is `/test/something` and your `try_files` directive is `try_files $uri $uri/ /test/index.php?$query_string;`, explicit internal redirect to `/test/index.php?$query_string` happens.

If your `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` PHP handler will be located **below** the `location ~ ^/test/(.*)$ { ... }`:

- If your URI is `/test/`, an implicit internal redirect by `index` directive to `/test/index.php` will took its place on the first step; on the next step you've got your `/test/index.php` source code in response due to the static content handler of `location ~ ^/test/(.*)$ { ... }`;
- If your URI is `/test/something` and your `try_files` directive is `try_files $uri $uri/ /test/index.php?$query_string /index.php?$query_string;`, explicit internal redirect to `/index.php?$query_string` happens;
- If your URI is `/test/something` and your `try_files` directive is `try_files $uri $uri/ /test/index.php?$query_string;`, explicit internal to `/test/index.php?$query_string` happens on the first step; on the second step you've got `/test/index.php` source code in response by the reason already explained.